# Can I post on a friends' wall as "Open Graph Action" or I need a classic "wall post"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-opengraph

Open Graph permissions let the app publish "actions" on user's own timeline.

If the app wants to post on friends' timeline does it need to post a good old "wall post" (publish_stream permission) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can clearly see from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#open_graph_perms there is no friends permission equivalent to 'publish_actions'.

And it makes no sense at all to publish an action on behalf of a friend, because actions are ment to be undertaken by users themselves; take the object/action combo „book” and „read”, for example – what sense should it make for *me* to post on *your* wall that *you* are supposedly reading *Harry Potter and the whatever* …?

Comment: I disagree with this opinion. It makes perfect sense if I want to publish my actions to friends wall. For Example I can see on my wall "Your friend xyz is reading <<some>> book." which make sense to me , like "your friend want to see this movie" this action will also make sense?

Comment: You will see that in your stream anyway, if you get their updates for what they publish on their wall.